# Indel quality from mpileup

Tags: python, samtools, indel, mpileup

Could someone please confirm that I understand this correctly? I have the res and qual columns from mpileup and I would like to match them to get the qual per base. It seems that the indel initiation (+2tt) has no qual so if I remove that I can get the phred with pythons ord().

```
res_with_indel = 'T*,t**,***T**t***,+2tt**,TT,.**.***.,'
res_without_indel= 'T*,t**,***T**t***,**,TT,.**.***.,'
qual = ":'21(:,838><*'915%2-;=@=99'*9'A$("
len(res_with_indel), len(res_without_indel), len(qual)

(37, 33, 33)

for base, quality in zip(res_without_indel, qual):
    print(f'{base} : {ord(quality)}')

T : 58
* : 39
, : 50
t : 49
*  : 40
* : 58
, : 44
...
```

To get the indel qualities then I need to match up each of the *'s across their respective indels lengths?

Is there a library that does that? Biopython maybe?

Thanks!